# Proof that Inner Join is Commutative

Tags: join, relational-theory, relations, relational-algebra

I'm trying to prove to myself that the order of inner joins doesn't matter, but, in an abstract sense, I'm coming up with nothing.

How would one go about proving that the order of a set of INNER JOINs that are executed to turn many tables into a single table does not affect the result set (i.e., prove commutativity and associativity of the INNER JOIN operation)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An inner join is the subset of rows from the cartesian product where a certain condition is true. Although the cartesian product is *not* commutative (*nor* associative), it is with regard to relational theory.

It is so because the [order of attributes doesn't matter in relational theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database)). If A and B are tables, then:

```
A x B = { (a1, a2, .., an, b1, b2, .. bn) | (a1..an) € A and (b1..bn) € B}
      = { (b1, b2, .., bn, a1, a2, .. an) | (a1..an) € A and (b1..bn) € B}  ((1))
      = { (b1, b2, .., bn, a1, a2, .. an) | (b1..bn) € B and (a1..an) € A}  ((2))
      = B x A                                                               ((3))
```

((1)) because the order of attributes doesn't matter
((2)) because the logical and is commutative
((3)) by definition of B x A

The condition for choosing which elements of the cartesian must be selected will be the same no matter the JOIN order, and as such, doesn't influence this reasoning.

The proof for associativity follows the same line of reasoning.

Comment: Next, we apply conditions. The proof is not finished for associativity. The conditions are totally independent of attribute ordering, so I think we're done for proving commutativity across a single inner join. How do I prove that applying conditions on (A INNER JOIN B) then (Result INNER JOIN C) is equivalent to (B INNER JOIN C) then A INNER JOIN Result? I think I may need more assumptions about my join conditions.

Comment: I haven't done it in detail, but define (A join B) join C, and compare it to how you define  A join (B join C). `(A join B) join C` = { (a1 .. an b1 .. bn) | ___ } join C = { (a1.. cn) | ___ }. Do the same for `A join (B join C)`. You will have  (condAB) and (condBC), and you will probably need to use commutativity and associativity of boolean `and`.

Comment: So, conditions AC may exist. I think I must assume that conditions only depend on individual attribute values and are not derived from some aggregate measures (e.g. ON b_2 = sum(a_1)). Otherwise, we definitely lose associativity. If so, can I wait to apply them until we have the full cartesian product A x B x C? I'm trying to see how to do that.

Comment: Good question. I've done joins with various operators and functions, but I am pretty sure I've ever done them with _aggregates_. I'm not sure how I would join with an aggregate (have you though of a realistic SQL example?). I don't think SQL aggregates are part of RT. This is an extension, in the same way that the _order_ of attributes in a SELECT statement, having duplicate rows, or having an ORDER BY are. So, I would _start_ by assuming that your conditions are _f(attributes of rows)_, which is what relational theory does.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I think we need to actually restrict the conditions to f(attributes of a single Cartesian product result row), so that a row is never compared to some quantity dependent on another row in the final, full Cartesian product result set. But, if we make that restriction on conditions, still, I don't know why we are allowed to apply the conditions after the full cartesian product of N INNER-JOINed tables instead of at each step. Do you know why?

Comment: And yes, here is a hypothetical use case. Let's say a Boeing, Inc. has ASSETS table: asset_id, asset_description (a string), and asset_value in Euro. Let's say the company wants to sell all ASSETS off to a single potential buyer and show that particular buyer what he is buying. They have a table of potential BUYERS: buyer_id, buyer_name and cash_available. Then, we do SELECT buyer_name, asset_description, asset_value FROM ASSETS INNER JOIN BUYERS ON-WHERE BUYERS.cash_available >= sum(asset_value). Result table can be used to SELECT a specific buyer and show them what they're buying.

Comment: I use ON-WHERE as a general term referring to ON or WHERE, since they're both ways to specify conditions restricting the result set. However, it seems WHERE is applied before certain operations. What I said may not even be valid SQL in any SQL implementation at this point, but the query seems clear enough to execute if a SQL database has the capability to execute it.

Comment: You could do something like that on SQL, but the aggregation would have to be done before, to get just sum(asset_value), which would just be a constant in `SELECT * FROM Buyers CROSS JOIN Assets WHERE cash_available > const`